# Set the entire component to GrayScale compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a disabled state for a custom component in compose.
The disabled state involves having the entire component set to grayscale with an alpha of 0.8f.
I tried drawing a rect on top of the component content with BlendMode.Saturation like so;

```
Surface(
 modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.drawWithCache {
  onDrawWithContent {
   drawContent()
   drawRect(backgroundColor, blendMode = BlendMode.Saturation)
  }
 }.graphicsLayer { alpha = 0.8f }
```

While this works perfectly fine, the only issue is BlendMode.Saturation is supported API 29 and above. How can I achieve the same behavior on API<29?

Attaching the component screenshot as reference.[image: Screenshot for component]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a `ColorMatrix` grayscale over entire rect

```
context(DrawScope)
fun drawGrayScale() {
    val colorMatrix = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorMatrix().apply {
        setToSaturation(0f)
    }
    drawRect(color = Color.White, colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(colorMatrix))
}
```

Comment: Tried this but calling drawRect() after drawContent() gives me a blank white square. Also just to clarify I need the blendMode.Saturation with a specific gray which is #2D2E2E

Comment: Okay so after a bit of looking around I realized drawRect() on top of drawContent() won't work directly but using the colorMatrix with setToSaturation(0f) would work if this colorMatrix is applied to the paint used in the canvas layer. Thanks @Nikola Despotoski

Answer (score 8):

Just to add something that could be nice for people that want to use this, following @Programmer123's answer and the [official documentation for creating custom modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#custom-drawing-modifier) I did this:

```
fun Modifier.grayScale(): Modifier {
  val saturationMatrix = ColorMatrix().apply { setToSaturation(0f) }
  val saturationFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(saturationMatrix)
  val paint = Paint().apply { colorFilter = saturationFilter }

  return drawWithCache {
    val canvasBounds = Rect(Offset.Zero, size)
    onDrawWithContent {
      drawIntoCanvas {
        it.saveLayer(canvasBounds, paint)
        drawContent()
        it.restore()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it is very readable and reusable, you can simply use it as

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(6.dp)
            .grayScale()
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @Nikola's answer this is what worked for me.

```
onDrawWithContent {
      val saturationMatrix = ColorMatrix().apply { setToSaturation(0f) }

      val saturationFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(saturationMatrix)
      val paint = Paint().apply {
        colorFilter = saturationFilter
      }
      drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
        canvas.saveLayer(Rect(0f, 0f, size.width, size.height), paint)
        drawContent()
        canvas.restore()
      }
    }
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! I added a good example of how to make more readable and reusable in another answer!